# can't delete ".git" using git clean -xdff

Tags: git, git-clean

`git clean` with the `-ffxd` option does not clean directories called `.git` - how can I do this?

Using git 2.32.0

```
mkdir myrepo && cd myrepo
git init .
mkdir src && cd src
touch code.cpp
git add code.cpp
git commit -m "my commit"
mkdir .git .git2
git clean -ffxdn
Would remove .git2/
```

but I want git clean to remove `.git` as well. but it is ignored.

from `man git-clean`:

```
       -f, --force
           If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not
           set to false, git clean will refuse to delete files or
           directories unless given -f or -i. Git will refuse to
           modify untracked nested git repositories (directories with
           a .git subdirectory) unless a second -f is given.
```

so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `.git` directory *contains the repository*. The working tree is "everything else": the stuff that's not in the `.git` directory (and not in any nested sub-repository as indicated by a `.git` in a sub-directory). `git clean`, being designed to work on/with a repository's *working tree*, won't *delete* the repository. The double-force option tells it to go ahead and delete sub-repositories, but it still won't delete the main one.

Comment: In your case, `src/` is neither untracked nor a nested git repository.

Comment: You might object (correctly) that the `.git` in `src/.git` isn't a repository because it is unpopulated. I think you could argue with the Git folks that this is a bug. I'm not sure which sides of that argument the various Git maintainers would come in on, here. I doubt anyone would think it is a big fire-y bug that needs to be put out quickly, though. :-)